# Building new computer

Tags: virtualbox

I am planning on going to a computer store, and have them assemble me a custom built very powerful machine.  What I would like to do is build a machine powerful enough that a Virtual Box running Windows 7 will be able to run Star Wars the Old Republic.  Is this possible, or will no matter powerful the machine, Virtual Box will have limitations that will make the game not work right?  I guess what I am saying is, is it possible to build a machine powerful and fast enough to run SWTOR as good as it would run on a regular $500-$600 computer with Windows 7 as the operating system, or will the Virtualbox screw it up no matter what?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using Wine or similar software through which you are meant to run solely non-Linux games rather than general software, etc.?

Comment: I have but I havent heard of anyone being successful running SWTOR on Wine.  If you think that is the best route, then is it possible to make a machine powerful enough to run SWTOR in wine and it be the same quality as on an average computer with Windows as the OS.

Comment: I must say that all the games I tried worked perfectly under wine. The only thing that didn’t work was visual studio. That's my experience, it depends a lot on drivers and hardware itself.

Answer (score 4):

Due to limitations of 3D graphics acceleration games will not run or will have a very poor performance in virtualbox.

With Wine/PlayOnLinux we can run quite a few games but by far not all. For a list of games working under Wine see:

- [Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/)

Note that game performance under Wine will be influenced quite a bit by the graphics card, and the driver we use. Therefore the tests above will give us no guarantee that the game will perform the same on a different hardware.

All games not rated "Platinum" will likely have issues but games rated "Gold" may be playble. Most games need additional configuration settings to be made.

In case we do want to play a game listed with a poor performance we will have to use Windows operating system for optimum performance.

Recently there is quite an effort to get more and more games running natively under Ubuntu, but this depends much on the developers of the game, and it's distributors.